# Extracting subarray based on logical indexing

Tags: python, arrays

Take a look at the following code in MATLAB:

```
a = [1,2; 5,6]
b = [-1,1; -1,1]
d = a(b(:)>0)
```

Now d will be the 2x1 array,[2;6]. This is because array b has positive entry only at the positions (1,2) and (2,2), and the third line of the code is extracting elements of a in those positions.

Is there an equivalent method in Python that does this? I searched numpy documentation but could not find any. In my actual code, I have multiple large, multidimensional arrays from which I would want to extract elements based on the elements of other arrays. Of course, this can be done with nested for loops but it would be much better if there is a nicer way like MATLAB does.

Comment: Search for boolean indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `a` and `b` are `numpy` arrays use:

```
d = a[b > 0]
```

In `numpy`, indexing is done with the `[]` operator.

Comment: Thanks this works! I have been trying b[:] > 0, b[:,:] > 0, but it's even simpler than MATLAB.

Comment: if there is a third array c, how do I add another condition using c? I tried d = a[b>0, c==0], d = a[b>0 and c ==0], d = a[b>0 & c==0] and none of them works..

Comment: `a[(b > 0) & (c==0)]` should work. What error are you seeing

Comment: it worked. Thanks again! The documentation of boolean-indexing of numpy did not contain explicit details to my dismay.

Comment: You're welcome. The parentheses is particularly important in this case, due to operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any libraries:

```py
a = [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
b = [[-1, 1], [-1, 1]]
d = [
    a_xy
    for a_x, b_x in zip(a, b)
    for a_xy, b_xy in zip(a_x, b_x)
    if b_xy > 0
]
```

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [5, 6]])
b = np.array([[-1, 1], [-1, 1]])
d = a[b > 0]
```